# iOS equivalent of Android finish()

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am relatively new to iOS development. I developed an app for Android first, and now am porting it to iOS. One thing that I can't figure out is how to make a `ViewController` "go away". I'm accustomed to the `finish()` method in Android. With that method, the current activity ends itself and the user is presented with the the previous screen that was open prior to opening the current screen.

What I'm trying to accomplish is making my "create" screen go away after a record is saved. In the Android world, I would just call the `finish()` method and that would be taken care of. What is the iOS equivalent?

I have tried the following code in my iOS app, hoping that the view would be animated away.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Edit:
The view was presented as below.

```
SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView"]; 
controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:vc];
self.sideMenu.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
[self.sideMenu setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

where `controllers` is defined as such:

```
NSArray *controllers = nil;
```

Comment: How is your view controller shown on the screen? The only way to remove it is to undo how it is shown.

Comment: So are you trying to make SettingsViewController go away? Where do you want it to go to? It is the only view controller in the stack from the code that you have shown.

Comment: I'm developing my app with a side menu. When the app loads, one screen is presented. The user has the option to open a side menu and select a menu item from there. The code in my edit above is executed when the user selects an item from the side menu.

Comment: Okay. I guess I am still not understanding what you mean by the fact that you want the create screen to "go away". That is very vague. Do you want the side menu to be displayed again? Do you want to remove all view controllers completely and show a black screen? Do you want to go to the home screen?

Comment: What I would like to happen is to display whatever screen was visible prior to the user opening up the current screen. When the user initially opens my app, they are presented with a screen that pull and displays an RSS feed. Then they can open up the menu and select an item from there. One of those menu items is to be able to track some information. When the user saves that info (i.e. enters data, clicks the dave button), I would like for that screen to "go away" and display the last visible screen. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well then wouldn't you need to save the last ViewController when the create menu item is tapped and then setup a delegate system, so a method on the class that code snippet above is from is called when the user clicks the save button. Then you can save the data and swap the view controller for the previously saved one in a similar manner to above. Alternatively, you could just a modal view controller.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How did you present this view controller?

Did you use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`? If so, you want something like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

If you are using `pushViewController:animated:`, you are not talking about a modal view. You are talking about a normal ViewController you pushed onto the stack. To "undo" this, you need to pop the view controller:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: I added the code I used to present the current view controller to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Though `finish()` and `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]` are similar in terms of functionality, but they are not exactly same, when we call `finish()` method in the Android, we are programatically telling the Android system to destroy the activity completely from the memory, when we override the `onDestroy()` activity life cycle callback and add a log, then logs are shown when `finish()` is called. `onDestroy()` is also called when the system needs resources and it frees the memory by finishing the activity. But

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

does not remove the UIViewController instance from the memory, the equivalent callback method for onDestroy() in IOS is viewDidUnload() which is not called on the message dismissViewController. I think the IOS system can only free the memory for the UIViewController instance when system needs resources but we can't programatically do that.

Answer (score 0):

after pushing your viewcontroller call this method

```
func finish(){
var navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers //To get all UIViewController stack as Array
navigationArray!.remove(at: (navigationArray?.count)! - 2) // To remove previous UIViewController
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationArray!
}
```